# Count of records by category, including zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have a table in the following format:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Id | user_name | submitted  |  reviewed  |  returned  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | tom       | 01-01-2020 | 02-01-2020 |            |
| 2  | mary      | 01-15-2020 |            |            |
| 3  | joe       | 01-25-2020 | 02-07-2020 | 03-04-2020 |
| 4  | tom       | 01-07-2020 |            |            |
| 5  | tom       | 01-04-2020 |            |            |
| 6  | mary      | 01-16-2020 |            |            |
| 7  | joe       | 02-08-2020 | 02-08-2020 | 03-07-2020 |
| 8  | mary      | 01-05-2020 | 01-20-2020 | 03-19-2020 |
| 9  | joe       | 01-21-2020 | 02-09-2020 |            |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query that counts the Submitted, Reviewed, and Returned records for each user, where "Submitted" is any records where submitted date in not null and reviewed and returned are null. "Reviewed" is any records where submitted and reviewed dates are not null and returned date is null.  "Returned is any record where submitted, reviewed and returned dates are not null.

The desired output would be as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| user_name | # Submitted | # Reviewed | # Returned |
-----------------------------------------------------
| joe       |      0      |      1     |      2     |
| mary      |      2      |      0     |      1     |
| tom       |      2      |      1     |      0     |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I tried doing three separate counts queries grouped by user_name, but those miss the zeros.  I'm very new to sql so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no question here, you are not presenting any problem you encounter with any query.

Comment: Hi Pablo.  Sorry had issues getting the formatting correct.  Hopefully clarified now.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: We need to see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `count()`.  Based on your sample data, you can look at each column individually:

```
select user_name,
       count(submitted) as num_submitted,
       count(reviewed) as num_reviewed,
       count(returned) as num_returned
from t
group by user_name;
```

There are no examples, for instance, where `returned` is non-`NULL` and either of the other columns are `NULL`.

If that is actually possibly, you could use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_name,
       count(submitted) as num_submitted,
       sum(case when submitted is not null and reviewed is not null then 1 else 0 end) as num_reviewed,
       sum(case when submitted is not null and reviewed is not null and returned is not null then 1 else 0 end) as num_returned
from t
group by user_name;
```

You could also use `count()` and play games with arithmetic:

```
select user_name,
       count(submitted) as num_submitted,
       count(day(submitted) + day(reviewed)) as num_reviewed,
       count(day(submitted) + day(reviewed) + day(returned)) as num_returned
from t
group by user_name;
```

This works because `day()` returns `NULL` if the value is `NULL`.  And `+` returns `NULL` if any value is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  This did the trick.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [id] INT
   ,[user_name] NVARCHAR(128)
   ,[submitted] DATE 
   ,[reviewed] DATE 
   ,[returned] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([id], [user_name], [submitted], [reviewed], [returned])
VALUES (1, 'tom', '01-01-2020', '02-01-2020', NULL)
      ,(2, 'mary', '01-15-2020', NULL, NULL)
      ,(3, 'joe', '01-25-2020', '02-07-2020', '03-04-2020')
      ,(4, 'tom', '01-07-2020', NULL, NULL)
      ,(5, 'tom', '01-04-2020', NULL, NULL)
      ,(6, 'mary', '01-16-2020', NULL, NULL)
      ,(7, 'joe', '02-08-2020', '02-08-2020', '03-07-2020')
      ,(8, 'mary', '01-05-2020', '01-20-2020', '03-19-2020')
      ,(9, 'joe', '01-21-2020', '02-09-2020', NULL);

SELECT [user_name]
      ,SUM(IIF([returned] IS NULL AND [reviewed] IS NULL AND [submitted] IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS [ # Submitted]
      ,SUM(IIF([returned] IS NULL AND [reviewed] IS NOT NULL AND [submitted] IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS [# Reviewed]
      ,SUM(IIF([returned] IS NOT NULL AND [reviewed] IS NOT NULL AND [submitted] IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS [# Returned]
FROM @DataSource
GROUP BY [user_name];
```